# Converting from British National Grid to Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, excel

I have a set of shapefiles for Europe which are in Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area (LAEA) projection:
[image: LAEA screenshot in ArcMap 10.4]

I am working in the UK and have a list of points in British National Grid (BNG) projection (GCS_OSGB_1936).

I need to accurately display the BNG points on top of a grid (shapefile) that is in LAEA, and number the grid cells that contain a point.

In ArcMap 10.4 I have set the data frame (Layers) to BNG and so I can correctly display my points (and OS basemaps). When I add the LAEA layers there is a Geographic Coordinate Systems Warning with the following info (that provides no other options in the dropdown boxes):

[image: transformation info screenshot]

When I click 'close' the LAEA layers draw and look to be in vaguely the right location over the OS BNG data, but not exactly...

(The same happens in reverse if I set the data frame to LAEA and then try to add the BNG points)

If I try 'defining projection' of the BNG points and setting them to LAEA, then it ends up drawing them in the middle of Europe (definitely not correct!)

Can anyone suggest a way to ensure that my BNG points and LAEA grid are correctly aligned to one another?

Likewise if there is a way of converting the points directly from BNG to LAEA in Excel that would also be useful.

Comment: Can you post the "spheroid" parameters? They're just below the CRS details that are showing in your screen-grab. Also, can you guesstimate how far off the two layers are now? Is it a mostly north-south offset?

Comment: On the first screenshot - there is one more line of info not captured in the screen grab which says: 'Angular Unit': 'Degree'      is that what you need?

Comment: Visually I'd say it looks like the LAEA layers are too far North (maybe 3km or so) and too far West (approx. 1.5km) - although this is difficult to tell precisely as I'm visually comparing a complex (wiggly) catchment outline against a 5 x 5 km grid version of the same catchment.

Comment: My mistake,  I thought the ellipsoid parameters were in that box. Open the data's property page in arccatalog and get them there,  please. There's a couple possibilities  and I'm trying to figure out which is the best to try!

Comment: Projection: Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area
false_easting: 0.0
false_northing: 0.0
central_meridian: 9.0
latitude_of_origin: 48.0
Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_unnamed ellipse
Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
Datum: D_unknown
  **Spheroid: Unknown**
    Semimajor Axis: 6378388.0
    Semiminor Axis: 6378388.0
    Inverse Flattening: 0.0

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  With no answers attempted within 6 months I think it is time that you considered reviewing your question to try and make it clearer.